# Can I separate `init.lua` to different components in Hammerspoon?

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

I would like to separate `init.lua` script used in Hammerspoon to enhance the readability and maintainance.

So it looks like the following:

- init.lua
- AppWatcher.lua
- WiFiWatcher.lua
- KeyRemap.lua

And then from within `init.lua` I would read these files and make the watcher activate.

However, it seems that there is no such function defined (maybe I may be missing it, though). Is it possible to separate the logic like that in Hammerspoon?

Comment: Usually you would do it with `require()` or `dofile()`. Not sure if those are available in your environment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using [require](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require).

If you put your Lua files in `~/.hammerspoon/`, you can then load them using `require('modulename')`. For example, if you have the following modules:

- `~/.hammerspoon/AppWatcher.lua`
- `~/.hammerspoon/WiFiWatcher.lua`
- `~/.hammerspoon/KeyRemap.lua`

Then you can load them from `~/.hammerspoon/init.lua` like this:

```
local AppWatcher  = require('AppWatcher')
local WiFiWatcher = require('WiFiWatcher')
local KeyRemap    = require('KeyRemap')
```

You can load any Lua modules, as long as they appear in [package.path](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path). To see the directories you can use, take a look at HammerSpoon's [package.path setup file](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/blob/d6c78d0f5ec74b23ea8d3a050fa694ce086ad2ae/Hammerspoon/setup.lua). This references the default Lua package.path, which is defined in [luaconf.h](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/luaconf.h.html).

If you want to put your Lua modules in a directory not included in package.path, you can do it by adding them to the `LUA_PATH_5_3` or `LUA_PATH` environment variables.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Seems that the return value of the `require` function is a boolean value. `hs.alert.show(AppWatcher)` showed `true`.

Comment: The return value is whatever is returned from the module. Often it will be a table that contains all the functions the module is exporting. That particular module must be returning true on success and false on failure, or something like that.

Comment: What if you have a spoon, and want to separate it into multiple files? Can the main spoon/init.lua file include other files?

Comment: As long as the modules you are trying to load are in Lua's package.path, you should be able to load them from anywhere. (Again, though, I don't have a Mac, so I can't actually test this out.)